# Should "glamourous" be considered incorrect?

Tags: adjectives, word-usage, orthography, o-ou

The [Wiktionary entry for *glamourous*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/glamourous), for what it's worth, claims that it is "a common British spelling", but many native English speakers dismiss it as incorrect. Some, though, draw a distinction between "glamorous" and "glamourous", saying that the latter is a valid, British spelling.

What's your take on this?

Comment: Oddly enough, "glamourous" is what I would default to here in the US.  Although spellcheck has it underlined right now, so I'd probably change it, as I have no strong feelings either way.

Comment: I really wouldn’t trust Wikipedia. If it were me doing it, I’d use *glamour* and *glamorous*, but I’m corrupt and no longer count as an innocent/native speaker of anything. As @NeilCoffey correctly observes, at the end of the day it comes down to a matter a personal choice. That’s not a bad thing.

Answer (score 18):

**Edit** in response to comments: as has been pointed out in the other answers, the spelling *glamourous* is included in the Oxford English Dictionary, which is why my answer doesn't so much as address the question of *whether* it is considered wrong by everyone, but rather tries to *quantify* its popularity — or, as it turns out, the lack thereof.

---

Here are the usage stats from the [British National Corpus (BNC)](http://www.natcorp.ox.ac.uk/) and the [Corpus of Contemporary American English (COCA)](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/):

```
              BNC   COCA
glamorous     562   2375
glamourous      9     22
```

So the spelling without the *u* is preferred on both sides of the pond, though the preference is marginally stronger in the US (99.1%) than in the UK (98.4%).

Here's a breakdown by publication type:

```
                  ou/o  ratio (%)

MAGAZINE  (BNC)   4/114   3.5
NEWSPAPER (BNC)   3/109   2.8
MISC      (BNC)   2/113   1.8
FICTION   (COCA)  5/392   1.3
MAGAZINE  (COCA)  8/811   1.0
NEWSPAPER (COCA)  5/535   0.9
ACADEMIC  (COCA)  1/120   0.8
FICTION   (BNC)   0/142   0     
NON-ACAD  (BNC)   0/50    0     
ACADEMIC  (BNC)   0/17    0
```

This means that *relatively* speaking, you are most likely to encounter the spelling *glam**ou**rous* in British magazines and newspapers, but seeing the *absolute* numbers you might consider yourself lucky if you encounter it at all.

So, both spellings are used — and in print, not just in YouTube comments —, but if you want to be on the safe side, *glam**o**rous* is the way to go.

Comment: There's nothing inconsequential about my question. It did come to my attention that "glamorous" is far more common, to say the least, but I've been wondering whether glamourous should really be considered wrong, as stated by some native speakers on a another forum. I'm happy to find out it's not regarded as such by most contributors of this site...

Comment: -1: The implication of your final *"both spellings are used"* is that somehow **glamourous** might be considered "correct" by some people. All those corpus results are saying is that slightly more Brits (still only 1.6%) spell it ***wrong***. But so do apparently 0.9% of Americans, despite the fact that they very rarely write *"glamour"* in the first place.

Comment: @FumbleFingers it wasn't my intention to *imply* that it might be considered correct by some people; it was my intention to *assume* that. As David points out in his answer (which predates mine), you will find "glamourous" in the OED. So I *take it for granted* that it is considered correct by some people. My answer is to quantify, not to prove, as a proof is not necessary. But I guess I should have expressly stated just that in the answer proper.

Comment: The OED includes *glamourous* as an “Also” spelling for the more standard *glamorous*. The only 6 head words returned for **\*ourous** are *anomourous*, *anourous*, *brachyurous* | *brachyourous*, † *enˈdeavourous*, † *ˈfavourous*, and   † *ˈhonorous* | *honourous*. If you search instead for “variant spellings” (which includes historical forms) of the form **\*ourous**, you then get 23 results, of which *glamourous* is one. Me, I always thought *glamour* was the standard spelling in America,too, but that’s less than clear. These *glamour, glamorous* are OED2 entries, still unupdated for OED3.

Comment: P.S. Are you sure the difference in percentage between US and UK is even statistically significant?

Answer (score 5):

Not being British, I hesitate to comment.  However, the OED(1973) entry for "glamorous" begins with the words "also glamourous".  This means it's valid, although I believe that most speakers of British English would not use it.

Comment: You make it sound like the compilers of the OED are party to some divine judgement about what is "valid" that is based on revelation unavailable to the rest of humanity or unavailable from any other source...!

Comment: Not divine judgement.  Just thorough research and many, many person-years of hard work.  There is good reason for the OED to be widely considered the most authoritative dictionary of British English.  When the OED tells me that "glamourous" exists, I see no need to look for additional information on the subject.

Comment: Ah OK, well yes-- if the OED suggests that a word *exists*, then that's probably true (with some provisos about actual frequency/trends in usage, e.g. it came up in discussion the other day that the OED lists the head entry "run time" whereas in reality "runtime" is generally the used spelling)...

Comment: ...just that you said "valid", which seemed to be lending some other quality to the OED compilers' judgement.

Comment: And I wonder what "proof of existence" the OED gives you that a Google search doesn't, for example.

Comment: I used the word "valid" because that's what the OP put in the question.  It's hard to be precise about exactly what this means; but I think the key point is that when the word is used, the person who speaks/writes it wouldn't acknowledge it as an error.

Comment: OK, I would actually tend to agree with this interpretation and approach to what might be meant by "valid" (though I think it's not 'le mot juste') -- but I think it's worth saying this in your answer rather than sidelining it. (Though how exactly the OED compilers decide that the speaker/writer doesn't consider a particular usage an 'error' is a non-trivial issue, of course.)

Comment: @Neil By the time the OED (or any dict.) verifies and authenticates something, Google search would have traveled around the world a zillion times over. Each has its merits and each its uses.

Answer (score 5):

It certainly is not a common British spelling, and most people would probably shy away from using `-ou-` twice in a word. I would.

The ngrams for [British English](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=glamourous%2Cglamorous&year_start=1600&year_end=2008&corpus=6&smoothing=3) and [American English](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=glamourous%2Cglamorous&year_start=1600&year_end=2008&corpus=5&smoothing=3) look very similar.

Comment: +1 This is the correct answer. There are many words like this *(odour, rigour, humour)* where Brits ***always*** drop the first **u** when forming an adjective with the **-ous** suffix. The Wikipedia article cited by OP is simply wrong.

Answer (score 5):

"Glamourous" is not an *invalid* British English spelling but it is not a *common* British English spelling.

The stem of the word, when used on its own (without a suffix), can be spelt "glamor" or "glamour", so called US English spelling and British English spelling respectively.  However, when used with the "-ous" suffix in British English the stem is *overwhelmingly* spelt in the US English way, to form the British English word "glamorous".

To give you a measure of what "not a common British English spelling" means, a search of the British National Corpus for "glamorous" returns [562 occurrences](http://bnc.bl.uk/saraWeb.php?qy=glamorous&mysubmit=Go), while a search for "glamourous" returns [9 occurrences](http://bnc.bl.uk/saraWeb.php?qy=glamourous&mysubmit=Go).

I would say that the Wikipedia entry is confused between the common British English spellings of the words "glamour" and "glamorous": "glamour" is a common British English spelling, "glamourous" is not a common British English spelling.

The word "glamourous" does appear in the Oxford English Dictionary (2007).  It does not have a separate entry but appears as a listed adjective to the verb "glamourise".

Comment: Very good answer, probably the best so far, as it pretty much sums up all the other answers (and comments) in one place *and* adds insight of its own. Comprehensive yet concise. +1 from me.

Comment: @RegDwightΒВBẞ8 Thanks for the comment.  I started writing this "corpus" answer when there were only two answers those by Andrew Leach and David Wallace.  By the time I posted, you had already posted your "corpus" answer too.  :-)  The first table that you present makes the point especially clear.

Answer (score -2):

My personal take on this is: what does it possibly matter? Pick whichever of the alternatives you prefer and use it.

Remember that fluent readers don't generally read by picking out individual letters in the middle of words. It's quite likely that whichever spelling you adopt, most readers won't even notice (or, if they do, care).

Comment: I failed to mention (I thought it irrelevant either way) that it was my assignment to create a new word out of "GLAMOUR". It's glamorous/glamourous that suited the context given. The use of British spelling, "GLAMOUR", misled me into thinking that I should use "GLAMOUROUS".

Comment: @dreamlike Words ending in **-our** often but not always become **-or-** in compounds.

Comment: I'm surprised to read such a comment on your part. You always seem so precise with post wording, so careful in distinguishing nuances in terms, in always being a kind of watchdog to the proper use of the language, maybe even too much so at times. I do not understand this lack of interest in being precise with spelling, although I acknowledge the fact that most people read without actually noticing how words are spelt.

Comment: My point is that in this case, both alternatives 'glamorous' and 'glamourous' are used and which one you choose is of no consequence. You may as well just choose the one you prefer and dedicate your brain to more interesting issues.