# Is "vapourise" considered incorrect, even in British English?

Tags: orthography, suffixes, o-ou

According to [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vaporise), the British spelling of "vaporize" is *vaporise*, not *vapourise* as one might expect from the word *vapour* (and similarly, the Canadian spelling is still *vaporize*, not *vapourize*). The words "laborious" and "coloration" suffer from the same problem, and yet "favourable" doesn't. Why is this so?

---

And in case you think Wiktionary is a disputable source, the Cambridge Dictionary has no entry for [vapourise](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/spellcheck/british/?q=vapourise) either.

Comment: And the British spelling of "laborious" is "laborious". The British spelling of "honorarium" is "honorarium". Not to mention the British spelling of "coloration", which is (usually) "coloration". Did you expect English spelling to make sense?

Comment: I'm actually trying to ask about the general case of those words, so I'll include them as examples in the question itself.

Comment: Words ending in *-our* lose the spurious *u* when turned into longer derived forms.

Comment: ^ I thought that was the rule as well, but apparently words like "coloured" or "favourable" don't have this rule applied to them.

Comment: Joe, Pardon me, but is the question about *z*, or is it about *u*? Perhaps, both?

Comment: 'Neighborhood' is another obvious example of many.

Comment: I have just discovered that 'colourize' can be spelled in any one of four ways 'colorise, colorize, colourise, and colourize'. Whilst Oxford Dictionaries does specify 'favourable', I think it would not be unheard of to see it written 'favorable' in Britain. Others may disagree.

Comment: Joe Z., the Cambridge English Dictionary says (UK usually **vaporise**). See http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/vaporize?q=vaporize The Longman English Dictionary says the same http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/vaporize

Comment: @Kris: It's about the *u*. I've edited the question to make that clearer.

Comment: In French, it's *vapeur* and *vaporiser*. Two different vowels. I suspect this is the cause of the difference in spelling. Ditto for French *labeur* and *laborieux*.

Comment: Do make a note that not all British people use an *s* in *-ize*.

Comment: This is why the American system of not using *-our* makes so much sense (except for *glamor*, which Noah Webster unaccountably forgot to change but which some Americans use *-or* for nevertheless). We don't have to remember whether it's *neighborhood* or *neighbourhood*, *colorable* or *colourable*.

Answer (score 13):

## "Vapourise" or "vapourize" does seem to be considered an incorrect spelling of this word in any form of English.

To understand why, it helps to know a little bit about the history of words that are spelled with ⟨our⟩ in British English.

### ⟨our⟩ comes from a French version of Latin ⟨or⟩

Many Latinate words came into English from French (by which I mean, not modern French, but the [Anglo-Norman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anglo-Norman_language) dialect that was spoken by French speakers living in Great Britain). The British English practice of using the spelling ⟨our⟩ in some words where Americans use ⟨or⟩ usually reflects the phonetic development of Latin "or" to French "our" (in Modern French, as Peter Shor mentions in a comment, the "ou" has often changed further to "eu"). Therefore, in words that are taken *directly* from Latin (or at least, treated *as if* they were taken directly from Latin), without the intermediary of French, we would generally expect to see ⟨or⟩ instead of ⟨our⟩.

### The Latin spelling ⟨or⟩ occurs before suffixes that strongly prefer to come after Latin roots (*-⁠ation, -⁠ious*)

Certain suffixes, such as *-(a)-(t)-ion,* "prefer" to come after the Latin form of a root. As an example, the verb *destr**oy***, which has a form showing some French sound changes, cannot be used unchanged as the base of an *-(a)-(t)-ion* noun: we don't say or write *"destroy-tion" or *"destroy-ation". Instead, we have the noun *destr**uc**tion*, which contains the Latin spelling of the same root.

Another pair like this is *dec**eiv**e, dec**ep**tion.*

So, the spelling difference between *col**ou**r,* *col**o**ration* is parallel to an audible difference that exists for some other sets of words. Hopefully this is helpful for remembering it.

The suffix *-ious* also generally selects the Latin spelling ⟨or⟩, which explains *lab**ou**r* vs. *lab**o**rious.*

### ⟨our⟩ remains unchanged before suffixes that strongly prefer to come after whole words

Certain other suffixes are generally attached to complete English words of any origin. These suffixes attach to Latin roots only when the roots exist as independent words in English.

#### Inflectional suffixes take ⟨our⟩: *-⁠ed, -⁠ing*

All inflectional suffixes fall in this category. Inflectional suffixes for verbs include *-ed, -(e)s, -ing;* so we write the inflected forms of *destroy* as *destroyed, destroyed, destroying*, and of *deceive* as *deceived, deceives, deceiving*. *Destructed* does exist, but not as a form of *deceive*: it's the past tense of a different verb, *to destruct.* And **decepted* does not exist; it would only exist if there was a verb "to decept". Likewise, ⟨colored⟩ would only make sense as the past tense of a verb spelled ⟨color⟩; if you spell the verb ⟨colour⟩ (as you do in the type of British English you're talking about), the past tense has to be spelled ⟨coloured⟩.

#### Some derivational suffixes take ⟨our⟩: *-⁠hood, -⁠ship, -⁠ment*

A number of derivational suffixes also fall into this category. Many of these are inherited or native suffixes, such as *-hood,* *-ship* and *-ful*: there is no change in pronunciation or spelling between *neighbour* and *neighbourhood*, *saviour* and *saviourhood* (or *saviourship*), or *colour* and *colourful.* This category also includes some non-native suffixes, though, such as the derivational suffix *-ment* (from French), which generally attaches to a stand-alone verb, not a bare Latin root (so Collins gives *[discolourment](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/discolour),* from *to discolour,* and marks *discolorment* as an American spelling).

Fowler (1926; republished 2009) also mentions *-ist* and *-ite* as suffixes in this category. *Labourist, behaviourist, colourist* all prefer
⟨our⟩ in British English. However, *florist* does use Latin ⟨or⟩, as does *arborist,* from Latin *arbor.* Interestingly, *humorist* seems to be more common than *humourist* in British English (although both exist); see the [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=humorist%2Chumourist&year_start=1980&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chumorist%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chumourist%3B%2Cc0) and the [British National Corpus](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/) (which has "humorist" with a frequency of 15, vs. "humourist" with a frequency of 4). I don't think *-ite* is really common enough to be worth worrying about, but the example Fowler gives is "Labourite".

Words that are standardly spelled with word-final ⟨or⟩ in British English unsurprisingly keep the ⟨or⟩ unchanged when suffixed, forming words ending in ⟨orist⟩: *motorist* from *motor,* *terrorist* from *terror.*

### Either ⟨or⟩ or ⟨our⟩ seems possible in theory before the suffix *-able,* but the standard spelling is currently ⟨ourable⟩

Some other suffixes, such as *-able*, behave both ways, and can come after either a whole word of any origin, or a Latinate root. This suffix did exist in Latin, and it can be used in English after Latin roots (although for some words the spelling may change to *-ible*) as in *destructible.* However, *-able* is also highly productive after regular English verbs of any origin, so we also can say *destroyable* (even if some people might consider it less elegant). In some cases, we don't even use the word formed from the Latin root, only the one formed from an English verb ([we say *deceivable,* not *deceptible*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=deceivable%2Cdeceptible&year_start=1910&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdeceivable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdeceptible%3B%2Cc0)). Because of this, I think that both *favourable* and *favorable* are theoretically possible forms: to find out which is actually used more, it's necessary to consult a dictionary or corpus of British English.

Fowler advises using ⟨our⟩ before *-able,* and this is backed up by a look at the [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=colorable%2Ccolourable&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccolorable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccolourable%3B%2Cc0) for "colorable" vs. "colourable" in the British English corpus.

### ⟨or⟩ is usual before the suffix *-ise/-ize,* which prefers to come after Latin roots (although it can also come after English words)

The suffix *-ize*/*-ise* is Latinate, and often prefers to attach to a Latin root (we say *anglicize,* not **englishize*) but in modern English there are also many words formed by attaching *-ize* to whole English words (the Oxford English Dictionary lists *foreignize, jeopardize, womanize* among others). I think this is what leads to variation in the spelling of words such as *[colorise](http://www.onelook.com/?w=colorise&ls=a)*/*[colourise](http://www.onelook.com/?w=colourise&ls=a)* and *vaporise*/*vapourise.* There's actually similar variation with the words *[crystallize](http://www.onelook.com/?w=crystallize&ls=a)*/*[crystalize](http://www.onelook.com/?w=crystalize&ls=a)* and *[metallize](http://metallize)/[metalize](http://www.onelook.com/?w=metalize&ls=a)* (where the Latin stems, seen in *crystalline* and *metallic,* had double *ll,* but the independent English nouns *crystal* and *metal* have single *l*).

### Dictionaries rarely list *vapourise/vapourize*: it is not usual and is likely to be considered incorrect

Tristan r left the following useful comment referencing several British dictionaries that have entries for "vaporise":

> the Cambridge English Dictionary says (UK usually vaporise). See
> [dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/vaporize?q=vaporize](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/vaporize?q=vaporize) The
> Longman English Dictionary says the same
> [ldoceonline.com/dictionary/vaporize](http://ldoceonline.com/dictionary/vaporize)

I did not find any dictionaries indexed by [OneLook Dictionary Search](http://www.onelook.com/?w=vapourise&ls=a)  that have an entry for "vapourise", aside from Wiktionary, which calls it a "Misspelling of vaporise."

Based on this, I would guess that many British English writers would indeed consider it a misspelling.

---

The following question is also quite relevant: [Should "glamourous" be considered incorrect?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/67445/should-glamourous-be-considered-incorrect)

Answer (score 4):

British English spelling is — or has been — more variable than one might imagine. (Microsoft Word’s spelling dictionary and its ilk seem currently to be forcing a standardization —  or ‘standardisation’, as it would have me write.) Using individually compiled printed dictionaries as reference, here are some relevant extracts from Chambers and the Oxford English Dictionary (OED).

**Chambers (contemporary iPhone version and printed 1993 ed.)**

> ‘vaporize’ *or* ‘vaporise’

and

> ‘favourable’ *or* ‘favorable’ (esp US)

**OED (encyclopedic edition 1991)**

> ‘vaporize’

and

> ‘favourable’ (US ‘favorable’)

**OED (1926)**

> ‘vaporize’ (18thC citations also include ‘vaporise-’), but also ‘vapourized’, citing usage by Macaulay as equivalent to ‘vapoured’, having the different meaning, ‘filled with vapour’.

and

> ‘favourable’, ‘favorable’

This edition (unlike the later) gives both spellings, ‘favour’ and ‘favor’, with the note: “As with other words of the same ending, the spelling with *-our* is preferred in the British Isles, while in the US *-or* is more common.” In its examples the latest use of the spelling ‘favorable’ is by Hobbes in 1651 (although there is one example of ‘favorably’ from 1872).

(N.B. ‘-ise’ seems only to have become more frequent than ‘-ize’ in British English usage in the latter half of the twentieth century. The OED (1928), for example, includes ‘recognize’ but not ‘recognise’; and this is still the case for a pocket edition I have from the ’50s.)

Comment: The Oxford Dictionary to this day still lists -ize as the preferred form, so that might have just been to save space on the pocket edition.

Comment: I have done a some quick checking and as my amendment indicates it is not a question of using the pocket edition of the OED. Also, I found that my large mid-century English–French (Collins) and English–Italian dictionaries only have ‘recognize’. However using the index of a copy of the *Oxford Dictionary of Quotations* I do find examples of ‘recognise’ and ‘organise’ from 19th-century writers, in addition to the ‘-ize’ spelling. The 15th and 16th century original usages quoted by the OED are spelt  ‘-ise’, with the first ‘-ize’ spellings apparently in the 17th century.

Answer (score 3):

My dictionary, Gyldendal's Red Dictionary translates from Danish to British English and vice versa and is the most reliable one in Denmark (which is very reliable, even though Denmark is a small country).

It knows the word "favourable" and not the word "favorable". And it spells "vaporize" as so, just like the American spelling. Cambridge on the other hand has results for both "[favourable](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/favourable)" and "[favorable](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/favorable)", but neither one has "vaporise", Cambridge even redirects to "vaporize" when searching for it.

Also my British spell checking plug-in for Firefox agrees on "favourable", "vaporize" and is even cool with "vaporise", but it puts a red line under "favorable". This plug-in might not be that reliable, though, I don't even know who made it.

Comment: Hello. Welcome to English Language and Usage. Your fourth and fifth paragraphs have nothing to do with answering the question. Please do not write sentences that don't answer the question in the answer box.

Comment: Thanks. I would have written it in a comment if I was allowed to, but new users aren't, which is understandable. I think at least my forth paragraph was pretty well connected with the first three, and even though it didn't answer the question it was a conclusion to the first three that did. But yes, we must obey the rules.

Answer (score -1):

In British English, when words have an '-our' suffix (eg favour, humour & vapour), get another suffix (eg '-able', '-ous' & '-ise' ), they lose the 'u' (eg favorable, humorous & vaporise). *This is a standard rule, therefore there isn't the word 'favourable' in British or American English.*

There is a similar rule with the suffix '-ous':
Curious ----> Curiosity
But in this case, pronunciation changes as well.
*This applies for both British and American English.*

Comment: Not quite: see http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/favourable

Comment: Nor Chambers. See my post.

Comment: You should define what you mean by "another suffix." Existing comments and answers have shown that this is not always true for the suffixes *-able* and *-ise*; it's definitely not true for inflectional suffixes such as *-ed,* which the original poster seems to be confused about (he mentioned in a comment "I thought ["Words ending in *-our* lose the spurious *u* when turned into longer derived forms"] was the rule as well, but apparently words like "coloured" or "favourable" don't have this rule applied to them").

Comment: *therefore there isn't the word 'favourable' in British or American English.* -- From the OED: **favourable | favorable, adj.**