# Is it deodoriser/deodorizer/deodouriser/deodourizer? In British English as well as American

Tags: american-english, british-english, orthography

British English would usually use "-our" and "-ser" and American English would use "-or" and "-zer".

I don't seem to find an appropriate answer to this. Which combination is actually correct for British and for American English.

Comment: In British English, *-ise* verbs tend to be spelled with *-orise,* not *-ourise,* even when they're related to nouns ending in *-our.* A similar question: [Is “vapourise” considered incorrect, even in British English?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/153392)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you couldn't find the answer in a dictionary.

For British English it can (like most use-/ize words) be either:

> deodorize
>
> (dioʊdəraɪz )
>   Word forms: 3rd person singular present tense deodorizes  , present participle deodorizing  , past tense, past participle deodorized
>
> REGIONAL NOTE:
>   in BRIT, also use deodorise

[Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/deodorize)

In US English, it is deodorize:

> deodorize verb
>
> de·​odor·​ize | \ dē-ˈō-də-ˌrīz  \
>
> deodorized; deodorizing; deodorizes

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deodorize)

And it is never spelt with ou.

Answer (score 4):

In British English it's normally spelt either "deodorant" or "air freshener" depending on whether you want to deodorise a person or a room.

Apparently, according to [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/deodorize), "deodorizer" and "deodoriser" are both acceptable in British English, but I can't say I've ever heard of them in 30-something years of living in South East England.